# Why does this not work?

Tags: c#, list, session, gridview

I have a class which will act as variables to store data from textboxes:

```
public class Business
{
    Int64 _businessID = new Int64();
    int _businessNo = new int();
    string _businessName;
    string _businessDescription; 

    public Int64 BusinessID
    {
       get { return Convert.ToInt64(_businessID.ToString()); }
    }

    public int BusinessNo
    {
       get { return _businessNo; }
       set { _businessNo = value; }
    }

    public string BusinessName
    {
       get { return _businessName; }
       set { _businessName = value; }
    }

    public string BusinessDescription
    {
       get { return _businessDescription; }
       set { _businessDescription = value; }
    }
```

I then have the code to store the data from the textbox into a session and into a list (there can be many businesses uploaded to the database at one time) - database irrelevent for now. I then want to display the list of businesses stored into the session onto the gridview: (b = class business)

```
List<Business> businessCollection = new List<Business>();

protected List<Business> GetBusinesses()
{
   return (List<Business>)Session["Business"];
}

protected void btnRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Session["Business"] != null)
      businessCollection = (List<Business>)Session["Business"];

   Business b = new Business();

   b.BusinessNo = Convert.ToInt32(txtBNo.Text);
   b.BusinessName = txtBName.Text;
   b.BusinessDescription = txtBDesc.Text;

   businessCollection.Add(b);

   GridView1.DataSource = GetBusiness();
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

It doesn't seem to add the list to the gridview, can someone help?

Comment: Is GetBusiness() returning a non-empty result?

Comment: Well, how far have you got? Is `Session["Business"]` actually being populated?

Comment: Further, what's the purpose of adding an entity to `businessCollection`... and then ignoring it and instead retrieving `Session[Business]` again to databind with the list? Looks fishy to me...

Comment: As Nathan suggested, is GetBusiness() returning a non empty value. The List may not be null but it may contain 0 items.

Comment: After adding your object to the businessCollection, should not it be reassigned to the Session["Business"]? Also what is this funny business going on - "get { return Convert.ToInt64(_businessID.ToString()); }"

Answer (score 1):

Debug your code and ensure that `if (Session["Business"] != null)` actually evaluates to true.

If it is false then you are adding to a list that is never returned from `GetBusinesss`

Without any more information you can rewrite it like this:

```
    List<Business> businessCollection = new List<Business>();

    protected List<Business> GetBusinesses()
    {
        if (Session["Business"] == null) 
            return businessCollection;
        else 
            return (List<Business>)Session["Business"];
    }

    protected void btnRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Business b = new Business();

        b.BusinessNo = Convert.ToInt32(txtBNo.Text);
        b.BusinessName = txtBName.Text;
        b.BusinessDescription = txtBDesc.Text;

        var currentCollection = GetBusinesses();

        currentCollection.Add(b);

        GridView1.DataSource = currentCollection;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

I personally wouldn't do it like this, as it seems like you need an assignment to `Session["Business"]` but I don't want to change the logic of your code.

**Update**

I wanted to update this with what I *think* you wanted to accomplish.

```
    protected List<Business> GetBusinesses()
    {
        if (Session["Business"] == null) 
            Session["Business"] = new List<Business>();
        return (List<Business>)Session["Business"];
    }

    protected void btnRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        Business b = new Business();

        b.BusinessNo = Convert.ToInt32(txtBNo.Text);
        b.BusinessName = txtBName.Text;
        b.BusinessDescription = txtBDesc.Text;

        var currentCollection = GetBusinesses();

        currentCollection.Add(b);

        GridView1.DataSource = currentCollection;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not assigning anything to `Session["Business"]`

Answer (score 0):

There's a very strong chance that you're problem is caused by the fact that you are referencing the Business List object inconsistently. You've created an accessor for this object, so use it everywhere.

This:

```
        if (Session["Business"] != null)
            businessCollection = (List<Business>)Session["Business"];
```

Should be:

```
        var businessCollection = GetBusiness();
```

Note the use of `var`: I suspect defining businessCollection as a member variable is part of the problem. In any case it is bad design if your intent is to store the list in the session. So I would also remove the member declaration for businessCollection and stick with a locally scoped variable.